# sqoop 1.4.4, from oracle to hive, some field in lower-case, ERROR

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I am using the sqoop 1.4.4 to transfer data from oracle to hive, using sentence:

```
sqoop job --create vjbkeufwekdfas -- import --split-by "Birthdate"
--check-column "Birthdate" --hive-database chinacloud --hive-table hive_vjbkeufwekdfas --target-dir /tmp/vjbkeufwekdfas --incremental lastmodified --username GA_TESTER1 --password 123456 --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.50.12:1521:ORCL --query "SELECT \"Name\",\"ID\",\"Birthdate\" FROM GA_TESTER1.gmy_table1 where \$CONDITIONS" --m 1 --class-name vjbkeufwekdfas --hive-import 
--fields-terminated-by '^X' --hive-drop-import-delims  --null-non-string '' --null-string ''
```

it doesn't work, cause the sqoop use checking strategy in the tool.ImportTool

```
16/10/08 14:58:03 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/f068e5d884f3929b6415cd8318085fea/vjbkeufwekdfas.jar
16/10/08 14:58:03 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT "NAME","ID","Birthdate" FROM GA_TESTER1.gmy_table1 where  (1 = 0) 
16/10/08 14:58:03 ERROR util.SqlTypeMap: It seems like you are looking up a column that does not
16/10/08 14:58:03 ERROR util.SqlTypeMap: exist in the table. Please ensure that you've specified
16/10/08 14:58:03 ERROR util.SqlTypeMap: correct column names in Sqoop options.
16/10/08 14:58:03 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: column not found: "Birthdate"
```

However, if I don't use the double quotation marks:

```
sqoop job --create vjbkeufwekdfas -- import --split-by Birthdate
--check-column Birthdate --hive-database chinacloud --hive-table hive_vjbkeufwekdfas --target-dir /tmp/vjbkeufwekdfas --incremental lastmodified --username GA_TESTER1 --password 123456 --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.50.12:1521:ORCL --query "SELECT \"Name\",\"ID\",\"Birthdate\" FROM GA_TESTER1.gmy_table1 where \$CONDITIONS" --m 1 --class-name vjbkeufwekdfas --hive-import 
--fields-terminated-by '^X' --hive-drop-import-delims  --null-non-string '' --
```

null-string ''

The oracle gonna throw error, because the field has some lower-case letters：

```
16/10/08 14:37:16 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/1f05a7e94340dd92c9e3b11db1a5db46/vjbkeufwekdfas.jar
16/10/08 14:37:16 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT "NAME","ID","Birthdate" FROM GA_TESTER1.gmy_table1 where  (1 = 0) 
16/10/08 14:37:16 INFO tool.ImportTool: Incremental import based on column Birthdate
16/10/08 14:37:16 INFO tool.ImportTool: Upper bound value: TO_DATE('2016-10-08 14:37:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
16/10/08 14:37:16 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning query import.
16/10/08 14:37:16 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
16/10/08 14:37:17 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
16/10/08 14:37:17 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master.huacloud.test/172.16.50.21:8032
16/10/08 14:37:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/10/08 14:37:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1474871676561_71208
16/10/08 14:37:25 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1474871676561_71208
16/10/08 14:37:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master.huacloud.test:8088/proxy/application_1474871676561_71208/
16/10/08 14:37:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1474871676561_71208
16/10/08 14:37:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1474871676561_71208 running in uber mode : false
16/10/08 14:37:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/10/08 14:37:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1474871676561_71208_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1707)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "BIRTHDATE": invalid identifier

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:861)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1145)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1267)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3493)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.executeQuery(DBRecordReader.java:111)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:237)
        ... 12 more
```

I am so confused, any help?

Comment: why are you wrapping your column names in double quotes? Have you create table  like  `create table tbl ("Co1" varchar(20));` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, It could be a case-sensitivity problem. In general, tables and columns are not case sensitive, but they will be if you use with quotation marks.

Try the following,

`sqoop job --create vjbkeufwekdfas -- import --split-by Birthdate
--check-column Birthdate --hive-database chinacloud --hive-table hive_vjbkeufwekdfas --target-dir /tmp/vjbkeufwekdfas --incremental lastmodified --username GA_TESTER1 --password 123456 --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.50.12:1521:ORCL --query "SELECT \”NAME\”,\”ID\”,\”BIRTHDATE\” FROM GA_TESTER1.gmy_table1 where \$CONDITIONS" --m 1 --class-name vjbkeufwekdfas --hive-import 
--fields-terminated-by '^X' --hive-drop-import-delims  --null-non-string '' --`

If it’s still not working, Try the ‘eval’ first and make sure the query is working fine

`sqoop eval --connect  jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.50.12:1521:ORCL --query "SELECT \”NAME\”,\”ID\”,\”BIRTHDATE\” FROM GA_TESTER1.gmy_table1 where \$CONDITIONS"`

Comment: Actually the query is not a problem, it is a problem only when the 'Birthdate' column is used as the --check-column or --split-by

Comment: Ok, Have you tried tablename.column  like --split-by gmy_table1.Birthdate ?

Comment: have you tried the eval --connect ?. still got the same error ?

Answer (score 0):

As per sqoop user guide

" While the Hadoop generic arguments must precede any import arguments, you can type the import arguments in any order with respect to one another."

Please check your argument sequence.

Please try below..

sqoop job --create vjbkeufwekdfas \ 
-- import  \ 
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.50.12:1521:ORCL  \
--username GA_TESTER1  \
--password 123456  \
--query "SELECT \"Name\",\"ID\",\"Birthdate\" FROM GA_TESTER1.gmy_table1 where \$CONDITIONS"   \
--target-dir /tmp/vjbkeufwekdfas   \
--split-by "Birthdate"  \
--check-column "Birthdate"  \
--incremental lastmodified   \
--hive-import   \
--hive-database chinacloud  \
--hive-table hive_vjbkeufwekdfas  \
--class-name vjbkeufwekdfas  \
--fields-terminated-by '^X'   \
--hive-drop-import-delims   \
--null-non-string ''  \
--null-string ''   \
--m 1

Answer (score -1):

use

```
--append \
--last-value "0001-01-01 01:01:01" \
```